# Facebook api oAuth2.0 multiple clients

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, oauth-2.0

My current authentication architecture looks like this:

[image]

We only apply login via fb since our app requires fb to work.
My question is about what happens multiple clients (web, iOS, Android, ...) will authenticate.

Is the access token returned to the different clients the same for the same user?
If so, it means that the access tokens for the other clients will be invalidated when the access token for 1 client expires.
What is the common way to handle multiple clients?

Comment: No, access tokens obtained on different devices do not have to be the same. And one expiring doesn’t mean other, still valid ones will expire with it.

Comment: @CBroe Does that imply you would send a unique client identifier along with the access_token to the server, and store the authentication state (access_token) for each client independently?

Comment: Depends, on multiple factors. Do you have your own token/session system to mark a user as logged in after they did the FB login? Or do you need to send the FB token with every single request? Do you need to make server-side API calls, or client-side only?

Comment: @CBroe, all api calls to fb (except the one to obtain the access token, which will be done through the client sdk) will pass through our server. The idea was to send the fb access_token for every client request (didn't see the need to have our own since our app only works with fb anyway). So all calls to access fb resources should be server to server.

Comment: If you do not have a session/token system of your own to authenticate the clients against the server, then you would have to check if the Facebook token is genuine on every single request – that is not really recommendable, it might even make you run into the API Rate Limits quite quickly.

Comment: @CBroe My idea was to store the access token in the session once it has been verified once at our server. When the server-fbserver request fails because the access_token has expired, then only the access_token would be refreshed by re-authenticating. As was my understanding, this is also how the JS sdk does it...